# Bounding a probability using a strong mixing property

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, mixing

> **Definition**. Let $\{X_t, t>0\}$ be a sequence of real random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ and denote by $\mathcal F_i^k=\sigma(X_t, i\leq t\leq k)$ the sigma-algebra generated. For any positive $n$, set
> $$\alpha(n)=\sup\left\{\lvert P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)\rvert:
>  B\in\mathcal{F}_{1}^{k},A\in\mathcal{F}_{k+n}^\infty, k\in\mathbb
>  N\right\}.$$ The sequence is said to be strongly mixing if
> $\alpha(n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Consider the sets $A=\{\omega:a\leq X_i(\omega)\leq b\}$ and  $B=\{\omega:c\leq X_j(\omega)\leq d\}$, where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R$. Suppose the sequence $\{X_t\}$ is strongly mixing.

1. **Does $A\in\sigma(X_i)$ and $B\in\sigma(X_j)$?**

If the answer is yes, then I know that
$$\alpha(\lvert i-j \rvert)\geq \lvert P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)\rvert \quad (Eq.1).$$
as the mixing coefficient is the supremum of all distances between the probabilities.
The above result leads me to the second question:

2. **Suppose that $(Eq.1)$ holds. Can I conclude that $P(A\cap B)\leq P(A)P(B)+\alpha(\lvert i-j \rvert)$?**

It is more about real analysis. I don't know if $P(A\cap B)$ is bigger or smaller than $P(A)P(B)$, but as $P(A)P(B)$ is inside a closed ball of center
$P(A\cap B)$ and radius $\alpha(\lvert i-j \rvert)$, certainly $P(A)P(B)+\alpha(\lvert i-j \rvert)$ exceeds $P(A\cap B)$.

Can you help me to clarify these two questions?
I'm trying to find strategies to lower bound a random variable, and this idea came to my mind. The result of question 2 seems straighforward but is unusual as far as |I know. So I'm feeling insecure to apply it.

Comment: The answer to question 1 is yes as $A= X_i^{-1}([a,b])$ and $X_i$ is by definition $\mathcal{F}_i^i=\sigma(X_i)$-measurable. Idem for $B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [TheBridge](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/4437/thebridge), $A$ belongs to $\sigma(X_i)$ because $A= X_i^{-1}([a,b])$ and by the same argument, $B\in \sigma(X_j)$. For your second question,
$$
\alpha(\lvert i-j \rvert)\geqslant \lvert P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)\rvert \geqslant P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)
$$
and the wanted inequality follows immediately.

Comment: Davide, can you take a look on my new question? It involves dependence modelling and strong mixing conditions. It is a very specific question, and few people would understand the context. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4121713/modelling-dependence-under-strong-mixing-conditions